# MethodAccessException with Reflection on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, mobile, windows-phone-7

While working with reflection, I recently got to the point where I wanted to access an object (in fact, a static instance of an object).

The object itself is defined by an internal class, therefore there is no other way to access it. Instead of directly getting a parametrized constructor, I can access a static instance via the **Instance** property. With the help of reflection, I am also able to get this property and set it to a `PropertyInfo` instance - it is detected correctly.

However, I am not able to get the value of the property via `GetValue` (since it is called via **get_Instance()** in the internal class itself) and set it to an object because I am getting a `MethodAccessException`.

The internal class is marked with the `SecuritySafeCritical`, but I do believe that shouldn't be the problem.

Any ideas on why am I getting this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`MethodAccessException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.methodaccessexception.aspx).

It says

This exception is thrown in situations such as the following:

```
*      A private, protected, or internal method that would not be accessible from normal compiled code is accessed from partially trusted code by using reflection.
*      A security-critical method is accessed from transparent code.
*      The access level of a method in a class library has changed, and one or more assemblies that reference the library have not been recompiled.
```

Check if the assembly is properly compiled and your application has proper privileges.

Comment: Since WP7 applications run in a sandboxed environment, I am pretty sure this is caused by the fact that the call is accessed from partially trusted code - I understand that. I am wondering if it is possible to go around this restriction.

Comment: Is the class you're trying to access internal to your binaries or internal to the Microsoft framework libraries?  If the latter, then reflection should always deny access, as you would effectively be calling methods that are outside of the WP7 sandbox environment.

Comment: I have a similar problem as well. I was trying to access `internal` members (ctor/properties etc.). In my case it should be more likely to work since the reflection code and the reflected class is _in the same assembly_ but `Activator.CreateInstance` throws `MissingMethodException` and other access attempts either return nulls where it shouldn't (when the member is marked internal) or throws `MethodAccessException`... It seems that WP7 runtime simply treats `internal` as `private` when it's come to reflection. I suppose this is to avoid exposing private APIs to rogue developers.

Comment: Still happens to me on WP7 even for public instance properties