# WP7: Type.GetMethods throws MethodAccessException. Is there a workaround for this bug?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, windows-phone-7

I try to get a list of all methods of a type. Type provides the GetMethods method to do this. But unfortunately it seems to be incorrectly implemented. It works properly as long as there is **no overridden generic** method on the reflected type. In this special case a MethodAccessException is thrown.

Does anyone have a workaround for this WP7 bug? I'm fine if all methods except the generic ones are returned.

Here is a sample of a class that will throw an exception. Note: the none generic return value is intended to prove that the return value is not involved in the problem. Furthermore, the base method can be changed to abstract and the problem still remains.

```
public abstract class BaseClassWithGenericMethod
{
    public virtual System.Collections.IList CreateList<T>()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}

public class DerivedClassWithGenericMethod 
    : BaseClassWithGenericMethod
{
    public override System.Collections.IList CreateList<T>()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `incorrectly implemented.` I highly doubt this. Although, I can't see such an exception documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: This could be related to a problem I had with the Silverlight Unit Test Runner in WP7 - it crashed whenever I used a generic type in an assembly (even unused).

Comment: @Jon Skeet That's exactly my usecase. This exception occurs in my xUnit Unittest runner implementation when analyzing classes that have overridden generic methods.

Comment: I can't test it at the moment, but does this post help? http://dev.flauschig.ch/wordpress/?p=74 He uses `IsGenericMethod` property of MethodInfo.

Comment: No that does not help. I try to get all method infos of a type. But I do not care if I really get all or just none generic ones. This means I do not have the method infos to check if they are generic.

Comment: @Remo Gloor: does the below work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got it working. The following Type extension methods return exactly the same result as the .NET 4.0 implementation but without the MethodAccess exceptions thrown by WP7:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static MethodInfo GetMethodWp7Workaround(this Type type, string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        return GetMethod(type, name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.Any, null, null);
    }

    public static MethodInfo GetMethodWp7Workaround(this Type type, string name, Type[] types)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        if (types == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
        }

        if (types.Any(t => t == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
        }

        return GetMethod(type, name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.Any, types, null);
    }

    public static MethodInfo GetMethodWp7Workaround(this Type type, string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        return GetMethod(type, name, bindingAttr, null, CallingConventions.Any, null, null);
    }

    public static MethodInfo GetMethodWp7Workaround(this Type type, string name, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        if (types == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
        }

        if (types.Any(t => t == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
        }

        return GetMethod(type, name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.Any, types, modifiers);
    }

    public static MethodInfo GetMethodWp7Workaround(this Type type, string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        if (types == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
        }

        if (types.Any(t => t == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
        }

        return GetMethod(type, name, bindingAttr, binder, CallingConventions.Any, types, modifiers);
    }

    public static MethodInfo GetMethodWp7Workaround(this Type type, string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConvention, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        if (types == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
        }

        if (types.Any(t => t == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
        }

        return GetMethod(type, name, bindingAttr, binder, callConvention, types, modifiers);
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetMethod(
        Type type, 
        string name, 
        BindingFlags bindingFlags, 
        Binder binder,
        CallingConventions callConvention,
        Type[] types,
        ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        if ((bindingFlags & BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly) == BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
        {
            return types == null 
                   ? type.GetMethod(name, bindingFlags)
                   : type.GetMethod(name, bindingFlags, binder, callConvention, types, modifiers);
        }

        bool isBaseType = false;
        bindingFlags = bindingFlags | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
        MethodInfo result = null;
        while (result == null && type != null)
        {
            result = 
                types == null
                   ? type.GetMethod(name, bindingFlags)
                   : type.GetMethod(name, bindingFlags, binder, callConvention, types, modifiers);
            if (isBaseType && result != null && result.IsPrivate)
            {
                result = null;
            }

            type = type.BaseType;
            if (!isBaseType)
            {
                isBaseType = true;
                bindingFlags = bindingFlags & (~BindingFlags.Static);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static MethodInfo[] GetMethodsWp7Workaround(this Type type)
    {
        return type.GetMethodsWp7Workaround(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    public static MethodInfo[] GetMethodsWp7Workaround(this Type type, BindingFlags flags)
    {
        if ((flags & BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly) == BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
        {
            return type.GetMethods(flags);
        }

        flags = flags | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
        Type currentType = type;
        bool isBaseType = false;
        var methods = new List<MethodInfo>();

        while (currentType != null)
        {
            var newMethods = currentType.GetMethods(flags).Where(m => ShouldBeReturned(m, methods, isBaseType));
            methods.AddRange(newMethods);

            currentType = currentType.BaseType;
            if (!isBaseType)
            {
                isBaseType = true;
                flags = flags & (~BindingFlags.Static);
            }
        }

        return methods.ToArray();
    }

    private static bool ShouldBeReturned(
        MethodInfo method, 
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> foundMethods,
        bool isCurrentTypeBaseType)
    {
        return !isCurrentTypeBaseType || (!method.IsPrivate && !HasAlreadyBeenFound(method, foundMethods));
    }

    private static bool HasAlreadyBeenFound(
        MethodInfo method,
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> processedMethods)
    {
        if (!method.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
        {
            return processedMethods.Any(m => m.GetBaseDefinition().Equals(method.GetBaseDefinition()));
        }

        return processedMethods.Any(
            m => m.Name == method.Name &&
                 HaveSameGenericArguments(m, method) &&
                 HaveSameParameters(m, method));
    }

    private static bool HaveSameParameters(MethodInfo method1, MethodInfo method2)
    {
        var parameters1 = method1.GetParameters();
        var parameters2 = method2.GetParameters();
        return parameters1.Length == parameters2.Length &&
               parameters1.All(parameters2.Contains);
    }

    private static bool HaveSameGenericArguments(MethodInfo method1, MethodInfo method2)
    {
        var genericArguments1 = method1.GetGenericArguments();
        var genericArguments2 = method2.GetGenericArguments();
        return genericArguments1.Length == genericArguments2.Length;
    }
}
```

You will get the same result for the following class with .NET 4.0 and this workaround on WP7:

```
internal class TestBaseClass
{
    private static void BasePrivateStaticMethod() { }

    private void BasePrivateMethod() { }

    private void BasePrivateGenericMethod<T>() { }

    protected static void BaseProtectedStaticMethod() { }

    protected void BaseProtectedMethod() { }

    protected void BaseProtectedGenericMethod<T>() { }

    protected virtual void OverriddenProtectedMethod() { }

    protected virtual void OverriddenProtectedGenericMethod<T>() { }

    internal static void BaseInternalStaticMethod() { }

    internal void BaseInternalMethod() { }

    internal void BaseInternalGenericMethod<T>() { }

    internal virtual void OverriddenInternalMethod() { }

    internal virtual void OverriddenInternalGenericMethod<T>() { }

    public static void BasePublicStaticMethod() { }

    public void BasePublicMethod() { }

    public void BasePublicGenericMethod<T>() { }

    public virtual void OverriddenPublicMethod() { }

    public virtual void OverriddenPublicGenericMethod<T>() { }
}

internal class TestClass : TestBaseClass
{
    public string Property
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    private static void PrivateStaticMethod() { }

    private void PrivateMethod() { }

    private void PrivateGenericMethod<T>() { }

    protected static void ProtectedStaticMethod() { }

    protected void ProtectedMethod() { }

    protected static void ProtectedGenericMethod<T>() { }

    internal static void InternalGenericMethod<T>() { }

    internal void InternalMethod() { }

    internal static void InternalStaticMethod() { }

    public static void PublicStaticMethod() { }

    public void PublicMethod() { }

    public static void PublicGenericMethod<T>() { }

    internal override void OverriddenInternalMethod()
    {
        base.OverriddenInternalMethod();
    }

    protected override void OverriddenProtectedMethod()
    {
        base.OverriddenProtectedMethod();
    }

    public override void OverriddenPublicMethod()
    {
        base.OverriddenPublicMethod();
    }

    internal override void OverriddenInternalGenericMethod<T>()
    {
        base.OverriddenInternalGenericMethod<T>();
    }

    protected override void OverriddenProtectedGenericMethod<T>()
    {
        base.OverriddenProtectedGenericMethod<T>();
    }

    public override void OverriddenPublicGenericMethod<T>()
    {
        base.OverriddenPublicGenericMethod<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd grab them all (note the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` in `GetMethods`) and then filter out those that are generic methods (`MethodInfo.IsGenericMethod`).

Sorry for the VB, I know the whole world wants C# these days, but...

```
Public Function GetListOfMethods() As List(Of MethodInfo)
    Dim d As New DerivedClassWithGenericMethod
    Dim myArrayMethodInfo() As Reflection.MethodInfo
    myArrayMethodInfo = d.GetType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance _
                                              Or BindingFlags.Public _
                                              Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)

    Dim myArrayMethodInfoList As New List(Of MethodInfo)
    For Each m As MethodInfo In myArrayMethodInfo
        If Not m.IsGenericMethod Then
            myArrayMethodInfoList.Add(m)
        End If
    Next
    Return myArrayMethodInfoList
End Function
```

I just tested on WP7 using your sample classes and it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I need the methods from base classes as well and as I already mentioned I do not care about filtering out generics. So the loop is not interesting at all. I just want to be able to get ALL methods of a type (but I can live with a solution that does not return generics). 

But still +1 for pointing me into the right direction. It seems to be possible to workaround this bug by collecting all methods from all base classes.

Comment: Bounty awarded for pointing me into the right direction. But as its far from the answer I accepted my extension methods that behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Could you actually be misinterpreting the behavior you are seeing? I am thinking you are experiencing a valid security access issue and nothing to do with the implementation of reflection on WP7 (other than its security model).

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331891/methodaccessexception-with-reflection-on-windows-phone-7). Could the type you are reflecting, any of the methods in question or the Type assigned to T in your particular case be marked as [security critical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397858.aspx) with the [SecurityCriticalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute.aspx)?

Comment: After I reproduced the OP's example I am doubting this answer as I can't see any obvious security issue with the example

Comment: It's defenatly not a security issue because you can get the same result as given by .NET 4.0 using a custom implementation of the GetMethods overloads.

Comment: after toying with it myself i agree.

Answer (score 1):

I gotta admit that I doubted what you are reporting but it is indeed easily reproducible and does look like a bug to me. I think you should report it on [Microsoft connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/).

As for work arounds...

This will get you the members of the derived class and then the base class (including the generic) without error:

```
var m = new DerivedClassWithGenericMethod();
foreach (var method in m.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
    Debug.WriteLine(method.Name);

foreach (var method in m.GetType().BaseType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
    Debug.WriteLine(method.Name);
```

This can be generalized (quick and dirty implementation) somewhat like so (The EqualityComprarer should filter out base class members that are overriden or hidden by derived classes):

```
 class MethodComparer : IEqualityComparer<MethodInfo>
    {
        public bool Equals(MethodInfo x, MethodInfo y)
        {
            return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(MethodInfo obj)
        {
            int hash = obj.Name.GetHashCode();
            foreach (var param in obj.GetParameters())
                hash ^= param.ParameterType.GetHashCode();

            if (obj.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
            {
                hash ^= obj.GetGenericArguments().Length.GetHashCode();
            }
            else if (obj.IsGenericMethod)
            {
                foreach (var t in obj.GetGenericArguments())
                    hash ^= t.GetHashCode();
            }

            return hash;
        }
    }

    static class Ext
    {
        public static MethodInfo[] MyGetMethods(this Type t)
        {
            if (t == null)
                return new MethodInfo[] { };

            var methods = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

            var baseMethods = from m in t.BaseType.MyGetMethods()
                    where !methods.Contains(m, new MethodComparer())
                    select m;

            return methods.Concat(baseMethods).ToArray();
        }
    }

var m = new DerivedClassWithGenericMethod();
foreach (var method in m.GetType().MyGetMethods())
    Debug.WriteLine(method.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a `GetMethods(BindingFlags)`. Try filtering out the methods you are getting with the BindingFlags argument.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to filter generic methods using binding flags.